# Prove prime number p divides 1+...+n^{p-2}

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am working on a problem in number theory:

**Problem:** Let $p>2$ be prime. Let $n$ be an integer with $\gcd(n,p)=1$ and $n\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$. Prove that $p\mid(1+n+n^2+n^3+\dots+n^{p-2})$.

Right now, I am trying to solve this problem with Fermat's Little Theorem. The Theorem tells me $n^p\equiv n\pmod{p}$. Then I have $n(n^{p-1}-1)\equiv0\pmod p$, so I know $p\mid n(n^{p-1}-1)$. Because $p\not\mid n$, I know then that $p\mid(n^{p-1}-1)$. From here, I am stuck and cannot see how to proceed. Thank you in advance for assistance.

Comment: Hint: first consider whether $p\mid(1+n+n^2+n^3+\dots+n^{p-2})(1-n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $n\not\equiv1\pmod{p} \implies n \neq pk+1 \implies n-1 \neq pk \implies p \nmid n-1$.

As Greg Martin mentions, consider $(1+n+n^2+n^3+\dots+n^{p-2})(1-n)=1-n^{p-1}$.

By Fermat's Little Theorem, for any prime $p$ we have $n^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p 
\implies p\mid 1-n^{p-1} \implies p \mid (1+n+n^2+n^3+\dots+n^{p-2})(1-n).$

But $p \nmid n-1$, so $p\nmid 1-n$ and $p \mid(1+n+n^2+n^3+\dots+n^{p-2})$.